# S3 - Cloudfront - Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I have a s3 bucket where I store hls files,
and I need to be able to stream those files in a player,
if a use the default s3 url, It works, but It is not safe.

I read and I found that you can use CloudFront and create a signed url or a cookie.
Then I created a new Distribution with the following options

```xml
Origin Domain Name: Name of my s3 bucket
Restrict Bucket Access: yes
Create a New Identity
Yes, Update Bucket Policy
Allowed HTTP Methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Cached HTTP Methods: select checkbox OPTIONS
Use legacy cache settings
And then I selected whitelist and choose
Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Request-Method
Origin
```

And finally I selected the

```xml
Restrict Viewer Access (Use Signed URLs or Signed Cookies): yes
```

After creating the distribution I tried to access to a file through
zxxxx.cloudfront.net/ls/600/10/playlist.m3u8

And I got **Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value**

Until this point I think everything is working fine.

I created a ruby script to get those credetials the

```xml
CloudFront-Policy
CloudFront-Signature
CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id
```

If then I try to access to a file using a cookie or an url

```
zxxxx.cloudfront.net/ls/600/10/playlist.m3u8?Policy=&Signature=&Key-Pair-Id
```

I am able to download the file, it means everything is working fine again.

The problem is when I try to access the file through my rails app, I get the message: **has been blocked by CORS policy**

I read and I found that the request should be from the same Domain to be able to send the cookie 
I then added a CNAME to my cloudfront distribution called cloud.example.com 
And locally I created a record in the host file called dev.example.com, port 80

Again tried to play the file and I'm still getting the same error:

```xml
'http://cloud.example/hls/600/10/playlist.m3u8' from origin 'http://dev.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The cors in the bucket is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Range</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you enable Options method in the cloudfront

Comment: The `Allowed HTTP Methods` option under behaviours section of cloudfront is what i am talking about.

Comment: Yes, it is selected GET, HEAD, OPTIONS and in the Cached HTTP Methods I selected the OPTIONS checkbox as well

Comment: I think the problem is no the Cloudfront, I just made a request through Postman, setting the cookies and I get the file. I enabled de Cloudfront logs I see the cookies in the log file. But If a make a request through the rails app, I dont see the cookies in the file and I get a 403.

Comment: Fernando did you ever figure this out??  You've described my situation perfectly and I'm spinning my wheels over here.